# Curl not passing the value to the php file

Tags: php, html, post, curl

i have a file called c.php in which i am trying to pass the value of var name to cu.php for processing but all i get is a blank screen :/ is it an error or is it a null value that is being passed

and the contents of c.php is

```
 <?php
    $name = " hello " ; 
    $post= 'name = '.urlencode($name);

    $ch =curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL , 'http://www.xxxxxxx.com/cu.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,TRUE ) ;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

and the contents of cu.php is

```
   <?php

    $n = $_POST['name'];
    echo $n ;
    ?>
```

Comment: Which file includes what? Also both files you posted you named cu.php. Very hard to follow.

Comment: @David sorry about that the first file is c.php not cu.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `echo` the result and pass the params like this..

```
<?php
$name = " hello ";
$post="name=$name"; //<-- Simpler way
$ch =curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , 'http://www.xxxxxxx.com/cu.php');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST ,TRUE ) ;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
echo $r = curl_exec($ch);  //<---- echo here
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set post fields as an array like this:

```
<?php
$name = " hello ";

$post = array(
    'name' => urlencode($name),
);

$ch =curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , 'http://www.xxxxxxx.com/cu.php');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST ,TRUE ) ;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
echo $r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: thank you its working now but instead of getting just hello i ger +hello+